# Wortschatz - Leichtigkeit zu etw

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Kann man sagen

> Je nach der Leichtigkeit des Lesers zum Loslassen...

Mit *Leichtigkeit zum Loslassen* meine ich die Fähigkeit, mit Leichtigkeit loszulassen.

Es wäre also eine Abkürzung.

Comment: Ich denke, dass Deine Frage etwas mehr Kontext braucht, um zu verstehen, was ausgedrückt werden soll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die "Abkürzung" funktioniert so nicht. Es geht ja nicht um die

> Leichtigkeit des Lesers

sondern um die

> Fähigkeit des Lesers ...

also eine Eigenschaft des Lesers.

Du schreibst es schon selbst ziemlich perfekt:

> Je nach Fähigkeit des Lesers, mit Leichtigkeit loszulassen ...

Answer (score -1):

*Leichtigkeit* ist die Abwesenheit von Gewicht.

Was du eigentlich zu meinen scheinst, ist, wie *leicht es dem Leser fällt*, loszulassen. Das ist definitiv keine Abwesenheit von Gewicht.

Wenn du unbedingt eine Substantivierung brauchst, wäre der richtige Ausdruck *das Leichtfallen*, was natürlich absolut gruslig und unakzeptabel ist (aber es macht den Unterschied, zwischen dem was du willst und dem was dein Satz aussagt, klar.)

Ein klassischer Ausdruck, der aussagt, was du sagen willst, wäre

> Je nach *Bereitschaft* des Lesers zum Loslassen

Comment: Warum "gruslig und unakzeptabel"...?

Comment: @sermonionx Weil ich das so empfinde. Das sollte bei dieser Formulierung wohl offensichtlich sein. Wenn sich jemand unbedingt so ausdrücken will, ist ihm das natürlich freigestellt. Man müsste ja mehrere Substantivierungen miteinander verbinden: "Je nach Leichtfallen des Loslassens des Lesers..." oder etwas weniger (aber immer noch sehr) gruslig mit einem Infinitiv "Je nach Leichtfallen des Lesers, loszulassen"- wenn du das gut findest, bitte.

Comment: @tofro: an deinem Beitrag stimmen bestenfalls die Zeilenvorschübe - und selbst die sind falsch. Das ist so, weil ich so empfinde und sollte deshalb offensichtlich sein.

> "Leichtigkeit ist die Abwesenheit von Gewicht"

Ja, genau! und mit der "Unerträglichen Leichtigkeit des Seins" hat Milan Kundera sicher gemeint, daß er die Gewichtslosigkeit der Existenz nicht mag. Man kann übrigens "das Leichtfallen von etwas" bzw. "die Zugeneigtheit zu etwas" auch als "inklinieren zu" (oder, substantiviert, als "(das) Inklinieren zu" umschreiben.

Comment: @bakunin "Das Leben ist einmalig. Es ist angesichts der Ewigkeit ohne Gewicht, geradezu unerträglich leicht." - Milan Kundera

Answer (score -1):

Man kann tatsächlich nicht:

> Je nach der Leichtigkeit des Lesers zum Loslassen...

sagen, aber man kann (unter anderem) sagen:

> Je nach der Inklination des Lesers zum Loslassen ...

oder

> Je nachdem, wie bereitwillig der Leser losläßt ...

> Je nachdem, wie groß die Bereitschaft des Lesers zum Loslassen ist ...

> Je nachdem, wie sehr der Leser zum Loslassen inkliniert ...

> Je nachdem, wie gerne der Leser losläßt ...

> Je nachdem, wie sehr der Leser geneigt ist, loszulassen ...

> Je nachdem, wie sehr der Leser dem Loslassen zuneigt ...

und noch einige Varianten mehr. Welche davon die beste ist, hängt - neben dem Text-Umfeld, dem Adressaten des Geschriebenen und vielen anderen Faktoren - nicht zuletzt auch vom persönlichen Geschmack und Stil ab.

Comment: "Je nach Bereitschaft (oder Inklination) des Lesers loszulassen" oder "... des Lesers zum Loslassen".

Comment: @planetmaker: ja, genau. Der Möglichkeiten gibt es viele und ich halte es für unmöglich, eine erschöpfende Liste anzufertigen.

Comment: "Je nach der Inklination des Lesers zu Loslassen ..." und "Je nachdem, wie sehr der Leser zum Loslassen inkliniert ..." sind in meinen Augen alles andere als hilfreiche Hinsweise. So redet kein Mensch und das wird auch von Muttersprachlern nicht nur nicht verstanden, sondern darüber hinaus auch als Geseier angesehen werden. Das ist kein guter Rat, das ist vollkommen absurd.

Comment: Im Übrigen ist "Je nach der Inklination des Lesers zu Loslassen ..." grammatikalisch mehr als fragwürdig.

Comment: "Je nach Inklination..." klingt ausgesprochen geschwollen und "... zum Loslassen inkliniert" klingt mindestens grenzwertig; meinem Sprachgefühl nach sollte man das Verb so nicht verwenden... außer man möchte zeigen, dass man sich sprachlich überlegen fühlt (aber gleichzeitig, dass man kein Sprachgefühl besitzt und einem das Verständnis des Gesagten am Allerwertesten vorbeigeht). Insofern sollte man diesen Satz nicht als erste (und damit bevorzugte) Übersetzung oder Möglichkeit herausstellen.

Comment: Da offenbar wenigstens @planetmaker und ich so reden, disqualifiziert sich deine beleidigende Diatribe selbst. Ich werde mich nicht dafür entschuldigen, daß mein Wortschatz offenbar größer ist als deiner und ich noch Wendungen jenseits von "boah, äh, Alda" kenne. Hier ist übrigens der Link zum Duden-Artikel: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/inklinieren und nebenbei ist "Geseier" eine ziemlich schlechte Nachbildung von "Geseires", was jiddischer Herkunft ist und "(wehleidiges) Jammern, Klagen", etc. bedeutet. Daß "inklinieren" die Konnotation "wehleidig" oder "jammern" hätte, wäre mir neu.

Comment: @bakunin Komm mal runter! Insbesondere von deinem hohen Ross! Wir haben hier alle inzwischen verstanden, dass deinem außergewöhnlichen Wortschatz niemand gewachsen ist. Vielleicht solltest du *Diatribe* aber noch einmal nachschlagen. ;)